# Virtual particles, what do we mean by that?

Tags: virtual-particles

This is probably more of a science philosophy question, but when we introduce those off-shell particles to explain some three body processes weird behaviour, do we really mean that there are actual massive stuff going on into the Compton length, or is it just a formal and mathematical way to make ours predictions correct?
Given that the only real things are those who are measured, is there a difference between the two?
I'm confused, because if virtual photons carry the e.m. field from an electrically charged body to another, can we directly measure it? Shouldn't we be able to directly "see" them? Do we?
Thank you a lot for your patience

Comment: See also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230113/can-virtual-particles-be-thought-of-as-off-shell-fourier-components-of-a-field/276002

Comment: see my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276075/how-can-the-proton-include-top-quarks-if-a-top-quark-is-heavier-than-the-proton/276089#276089 and links therein

Comment: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/        well worth reading